# How to count number of legos?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image of Lego bricks which I have segmented in order to get only the blue and red colored bricks.

[image: segmented]

I also have two templates of bricks that I want to find.

[image: templates]

I want to count the number of each of the template bricks in the image. I thought of counting the number of circles on top of the bricks, but some of the bricks are flipped. How could I do this?

Comment: You’ll probably need a lot of templates, from many different angles, if you want to go with template matching.

Answer (score 1):

Counting the number of circles on top of the bricks could be a very difficult task. A better solution is to look after better properties such like the relation between the hight and the width of the brick.

A possible start for segmentation is as follows:

```matlab
E = regionprops(L,'all');     % E contains all properties
area = cat(1, E.Area)         % saves the area in a variable
cp = cat(1,E.Centroid)        % saves the center of the object
figure,imshow(label2rgb(L));
hold on; plot(cp(:,1), cp(:,2), 'b*');  % displays the center of the objects
```

It will show you your segmentation and will display some information about the properties of the obejects. From there on you will be able to look for what properties you are watching for and can select them in if statements. Depending on your image and your selected properties this could take up to 10 properties but most likely will be around 5.

For further information look here: [MATLAB segmentation overview](https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/image-segmentation.html)

Comment: I found another way which you can try to use: [MATLAB example](https://www.mathworks.com/videos/color-based-segmentation-with-live-image-acquisition-68771.html)